# iOS UITableView : clear section button

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I need to add clear button in table view section header. It is exactly same like the one in notification center. So when user clicks it, 'x' will change to 'Clear'. If s/he clicks it again, app will perform action. But any click outside this button, 'Clear' will be back to 'x'

How can I make this? Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this does not come out of the box. You have to create your own custom section header view. That custom header view contains a UILabel on the left side. On the right side you put a `UIButton` that has the title "X". When the user taps on the button, change its title to "Clear" and its state to `.Selected`. Only clear your table view section when the button is tapped and its state is `.Selected`:

```
func setupButton() {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("X", forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("didPressButton:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    addSubview(button)
}

func didPressButton(button: UIButton) {
    if button.selected {
        // clear your table view section
    }
    button.setTitle("Clear", forState: .Normal)
    button.selected = true
}
```

To put the button back in its unselected state add a background `UIView` to your section header view and add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it:

```
func setupBackground() {
    let background = UIView()
    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("didTapOutside:"))
    background.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    insertSubview(background, belowSubview: button)
}

func didTapOutside(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    button.selected = false
    button.setTitle("X", forState: .Normal)
}
```

To use your custom section header in your table view you implement the following `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
     // create your custom section header and return it   
}
```

Comment: I see. I thought there is an easy way to do it, but it is not. Thanks